# How to execute a powershell script from AWS SSM document and store the output into a variable

Tags: powershell, aws-ssm, aws-powershell

I am writing an AWS SSM document and using PowerShell as a scripting language. My task is to execute a PowerShell script with parameters from the AWS SSM document and store the output of the executed PowerShell script in a variable.

I have already searched and got a couple of links but could not find the exact answer.

Please share any thoughts or any links.

Note: I am completely new in AWS and powershell

Comment: What do you intend to do with the output .. ?

Comment: I need to execute some other logic with the output.

Comment: On the instance or on your client?

Comment: if I am calling script2.ps1 from the script.1ps1 then script2.ps1 will give some output and there is some other logic I need to build in the script1.ps1 on the behalf of the output parms.